Keep session active without logging out automatically
I intend to keep my session active without ending for 24 hours. On a computer or on a cell phone with the screen on, it works, but if you lock the screen after two minutes, the session ends. I will post my code:
First I configured php.ini:

session.cookie_lifetime   86400   86400
session.gc_maxlifetime    86400   86400

Now I'm going to publish the code, where I'm using it at the beginning of each page:
$lifetime = 86400; // 24 horas em segundos

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {   
    session_start(); // Inicia a sessão se ainda não estiver iniciada
}

// Renova o cookie de sessão para que ele expire após 24 horas do último acesso
setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), time() + $lifetime);

// Verifica se a sessão está válida (se as variáveis necessárias estão definidas)
if (!isset($_SESSION["usuarioNome"]) || !isset($_SESSION["usuarioSenha"])) {
    // Se a sessão não é válida, redireciona para a página de login
    header("Location: ../index.html");
    exit;
}

// Inclui a conexão com o banco de dados e define o fuso horário
require_once 'conexao.php';
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');

Where then I have a function that checks whether the session is active or not:
$(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
      $.ajax({
          url: 'logout_status.php',
          method: 'get',
          dataType: 'json'
      })
      .done(function(retorno){
          
      })
      .fail(function(erro){
          window.location.href = '../index.html';
          console.log(erro);
      });
  }, 60000);
});

logout_status.php
require("validsessao.php");
$response = array("logout" => isset($_SESSION['usuarioNome']) ? true : null);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);

Everything works fine, but when I use my cell phone and log in and leave the session logged in and lock the screen, after two minutes the session ends and it shouldn't end. Can you help?
I'll just add a note here:
I added logout_status.php to the code, a way to create a log file to understand what happens when I lock the cell phone screen, but if the screen is on, it creates the file and gives me an active session. From the moment I lock the screen it no longer sends information to the text file
require("validsessao.php");
$response = array("logout" => isset($_SESSION['usuarioNome']) ? true : null);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);

if($_SESSION['usuarioId'] == 350){
    $log_file = '/var/www/html/assets/utente/sessao_logs.txt';  // Defina o caminho para o arquivo de log

    $log_data = sprintf(
        "[%s] Sessão iniciada com ID: %s, Nome de Usuário: %s, Status: %s\n",
        date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        session_id(),
        isset($_SESSION['usuarioNome']) ? $_SESSION['usuarioNome'] : 'N/A',
        session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ? 'Ativa' : 'Inativa'
    );

    file_put_contents($log_file, $log_data, FILE_APPEND);
}


I'm not sure this is related to code. It might be a data saver or something. Did you check with another mobile?

@Abdulla Nilam Yes, I have already checked the phone and everything is as expected, I have Chrome running in the background with wifi and mobile data and even so, from the moment I lock the phone it seems that there is no communication between the application and the server

Is this a web socket? or normal HTTP request

Abdulla Nilam My website is localhost and is only certified on machines that are within my network. On cell phones this certification is not valid, so access is http://gestao.local, normal http request
